# Jersey: read uploaded file as JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I am able to upload a file in jersey in the following way:

```
@POST
    @Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void indexFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedFile,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo){
        System.out.println(fileInfo.getFileName());
        DAO.indexFileToSolr(uploadedFile);
    }
```

this gives me the file as a input stream.
This file contains an array of json objects in the following format:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "someTitle"
    }
]
```

I also have a POJO/ Java class representing this object like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyObj{
    private int id;
    private String title;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I am using `jersey-media-moxy` to automatically convert between POJO and JSON/XML at the time of incoming request or outgoing response. 
(I don't need to write any code for this, i just need to specify that the request will be in JSON format, or the response should be JSON, and the serialization/deserialization is handled by `jersey-media-moxy`.)

The issue is , i am not able to specify this behavior in the file upload method, i see no way of telling jersey or `jersey-media-moxy` to serialize the file to java objects.

I could not find any methods in `jersey-media-moxy` to actually read a InputStream and serialize it to a POJO.

NOTE: i can probably use `jackson` to read the json file and create a list of Java objects, but i am not very inclined to do so, firstly because that requires another library (it would be great if i can do this with jersey-media-mosy) and secondly, i am not sure whether there could be a easy way to just tell jersey that this file contains Json objects so, de-serialize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get the client to set the `Content-Type` header for the individual part that is JSON, then handling this is trivial. With multipart, each part can have its own `Content-Type`. For example part of a raw multipart request might look something like

```
--Boundary_1_1938025186_1463410894758
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="beans"

[ {"name": "peeskillet"} ]
--Boundary_1_1938025186_1463410894758--
```

You can see for the this particular part, the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`. If you can get this from the client, then all you need to do is have a POJO parameter like you would a normal JSON request

```
@POST
@Path("with-content-type")
public List<Bean> post1(@FormDataParam("beans") List<Bean> beans) {
    return beans;
}
```

If you were to try and use the above, and the client didn't set the `Content-Type`, then it would default to `text/plain` and the results are just weird. They are not as expected. From what I tested, it seems the bean property is set the entire raw JSON.

What we can do though is get a pre-deserialized body part, set the `Content-Type` explicitly, then deserialize it.

```
@POST
@Path("no-content-type")
public Bean[] post2(@FormDataParam("beans") FormDataBodyPart bodyPart) throws IOException {
    bodyPart.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Bean[] beans = bodyPart.getEntityAs(Bean[].class);
    return beans;
}
```

Notice instead of a `List<Bean>` I use a `Bean[]`. The problem with trying to get a `List<Bean>` is that we can't do `bodyPart.getEntityAs(List.class)`, as MOXy needs to know the generic type. So we just get it as an array. A `Bean[]` would also work as a method parameter, instead of a `List<Bean>`, as in the first example, if the client were to set the `Content-Type`.

Below is a complete test case, using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Run this like any other JUnit test. Only two required dependencies.
 * 
 *  <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
 *      <version>2.22.1</version>
 *      <scope>test</scope>
 *  </dependency>
 *      <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
 *      <version>2.22.1</version>
 *      <scope>test</scope>
 *  </dependency>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class MoxyMultipartTest extends JerseyTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Bean {

        private String name;

        public Bean() {
        }

        public Bean(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    @Path("test")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class TestResource {

        @POST
        @Path("with-content-type")
        public Bean[] post1(@FormDataParam("beans") Bean[] beans) {
            return beans;
        }

        @POST
        @Path("no-content-type")
        public Bean[] post2(@FormDataParam("beans") FormDataBodyPart bodyPart) throws IOException {
            bodyPart.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
            Bean[] beans = bodyPart.getEntityAs(Bean[].class);
            return beans;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        config.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                .register(MoxyJsonFeature.class);
    }

    final String json = "[ {\"name\": \"peeskillet\"} ]";

    @Test
    public void testSettingContentType() {
        final MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
                .field("beans", json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        final Response response = target("test/with-content-type")
                .request().post(Entity.entity(multiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));

        assertResponseHasBeans(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithoutSettingContentType() {
        final MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
                .field("beans", json); // No Content-Type
        final Response response = target("test/no-content-type")
                .request().post(Entity.entity(multiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));

        assertResponseHasBeans(response);
    }

    private void assertResponseHasBeans(Response response) {
        final List<Bean> beans = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Bean>>() {
        });
        assertThat(beans, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(beans.isEmpty(), is(false));

        assertThat(beans.get(0).getName(), is("peeskillet"));
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't have any other part, i only have a file. the file contains json objects, but i have no idea how to read the json out of that file and create a list of Java objects.

Comment: You don't need to read anything. Jersey will read it for you. Please take time to read the answer, test it out. Then if you still have problems after testing, let me know

Comment: I read the answer, it seems you are suggesting to set content type on the multipart form data that is sent from client to server. 
But this is not (exactly) my use case, i am trying a simple file upload, and i am able to receive the file as a whole , the content type is application/octet-stream, now this file contains json objects and i need to read it in Array or List.

Comment: With multpart there are always "parts" whether you are sending just one part (a file) or a bunch of parts (multi files). Either way, each part can be set a content-type, but the main request is still multpart/form-data, with individual parts having their own type. The example request I have above is just a single part in the multipart request, it is not the full request.

Comment: The second part of my answer explains how you set the individual part's content-type programmatically so that you set it to JSON. Once it's set to application/json, then Jersey will use it's usual deserializer (in your case MOXy) to deserialize that sinlge part. Please test it for yourself

Comment: so, should i change "application/octet-stream" which is received from the browser to "application/json" (using the way you have suggested)? 
(sorry i only know the basics of Jersey yet)

Comment: On the server side, yes. Just like my example shows. Then you should be able to do `bodyPart.getEntityAs(MyObj[].class)`. You should also use `@FormDataParam("file")`, since that is the part name you are using, instead of `beans` in my example

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Although i do not really understand why we should/can assign application/octet-stream to application/json, but this actually worked

Comment: When jersey deserializes the multipart, each part gets deserialized the same way as if it were a regular request. For a regular request, the only way jersey knows how to pick the correct deserializer is through the Content-Type header. For example xml and JSON have different Content-Type. So we tell jersey which serialized to use for this particular part, by changing the type. Otherwise there is no reader that handles conversion from octet-stream to pojo. Read the Jersey documentation section about "jax-rs Entity providers". It explains in more detail about the readers and writers.